# Pure CSS content tabs - Can't get content to show

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a set of tabs that each show different content, but in the area where the content for each tab should show, I'm seeing nothing. I've tried a couple different techniques  from online tutorials but I'm still stuck on what I'm doing wrong. I've set the opacity of the content to zero and I'm trying to trigger a change to 100, but if there is a better way let me know.

I'm trying to keep it to CSS if it's possible.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Pure CSS Tabs</title>
    <link href="css/actorpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="radio" class="UploadAudio" value="checked" />
        <label for="tab1">Upload Audio</label>
        <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="radio" class="UploadVideo" />
        <label for="tab2">Upload Video</label>
        <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="radio" class="UpdateResume" />
        <label for="tab3">Update Resume</label>
        <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="radio" class="MyAccount" />
        <label for="tab4">My Account</label>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="filler">
                    <div id="content1" class="UploadAudio">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content2" class="UploadVideo">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="content3" class="UpdateResume">
                        <p>3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content4" class="MyAccount">
                        <p>4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
font-family: verdana, helvetica;
}

.tabs {
animation: fadein .6s ease-in;
position: auto;
margin: 50px auto;
width: 90%;
height: 500px;
border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
z-index: 100;
}

.tabs input {

position: absolute;
height: 40px;   
opacity: 0;
}
.tabs > label {
transition: .5s ease 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 2em;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabs > input:hover + label {
background-color: white;
}

.tabs > input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    opacity: 100;
    z-index: 100;
}

.content{
opacity: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
padding: 10px 10px; 
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;

box-shadow: 0 0 20px #444;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #444;

border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;

}
```

Comment: can you please put it in a fiddle? (http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You gave `opacity: 0` to the entire `content`. put it back to `1` and you'll se the content. now you have to manage the tab click behaviour: fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Pf59s/

Comment: And if you want to make the first tab to have the active state, change `value="checked"` to `checked="checked"` or just `checked`. The `value` attribute of an HTML radio button does not hold the state of it being checked or not. Also, take note that CSS opacity is always from 0 to 1 (although 100 opacity will still work).

Answer (score 0):

Remove opacity: 0 on class "content".
Try adding class .hide {display:none;} to all #content1, #content2, #content3, #content4 and removing it only for that content for which tab is activated.